# How to initialize a lazy loaded collection outside of the transaction it was fetched in the right way?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, graphql, netflix-dgs

I've a spring boot application which uses Hibernate as an ORM and [DGS framework](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/) as the graphql engine. I've been struggling with finding ways to initialize a lazy loaded collection, the proper way. I've the following scenario:

```
application.properties
# The below has been set to false to get rid of the anti-pattern stuff it introduces
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
...
```

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Article> articles;

    ...

}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    ...
}
```

My `User` data fetcher looks something like this:

```java
@DgsComponent
public class UserDataFetcher {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @DgsQuery
    public User getUserById(@InputArgument UUID id) {
        return userService.findById(id);
    }
    ...
}
```

My `UserService` looks something like this:

```java
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public User findById(UUID id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(DgsEntityNotFoundException::new);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, I only want to initialize/load my articles collections from the DB when the user asks for it in the graphql query. For that purpose I created a child resolver for my articles which only executes when a user asks for the article in the query. My `UserDataFetcher` started looking like this:

```java
@DgsComponent
public class UserDataFetcher {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @DgsQuery
    public User getUserById(@InputArgument UUID id) {
        return userService.findById(id);
    }

    @DgsData(parentType = "User", field = "articles")
    public List<Article> getArticle(DgsDataFetchingEnvironment dfe) {
        User user = dfe.getSource();
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getArticles());
        return user.getArticles();
    }
    ...
}
```

But, the above started throwing exceptions telling me that Hibernate couldn't find an open session for the above request. Which made sense because there wasn't any so I put a `@Transactional` on top of my child resolver and it started looking like this:

```java
@DgsComponent
public class UserDataFetcher {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @DgsQuery
    public User getUserById(@InputArgument UUID id) {
        return userService.findById(id);
    }

    @DgsData(parentType = "User", field = "articles")
    @Transactional
    public List<Article> getArticle(DgsDataFetchingEnvironment dfe) {
        User user = dfe.getSource();
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getArticles());
        return user.getArticles();
    }
    ...
}
```

However, the above didn't work either. I tried moving this `@Transactional` into my service layer as well but even then it didn't work and it throwed the same exception. After much deliberation, I founded out that (maybe) `Hibernate.initialize(...)` only works if I call it in the initial transaction, the one which fetched me my user in the first place. Meaning, it's of no use to me since my use-case is very user-driven. I ONLY want to get this when my user asks for it, and this is always going to be in some other part of my application outside of the parent transaction.

I am looking for solutions other than the following:

1. Changing the child resolver to something like this:

```java
    @DgsData(parentType = "User", field = "articles")
    @Transactional
    public List<Article> getArticle(DgsDataFetchingEnvironment dfe) {
        User user = dfe.getSource();
        List<Article> articles = articlesRepository.getArticlesByUserId(user.getUserId);
        return articles;
    }
```

I am not in the favor of the above solution since I feel this is under-utilizing the ORM itself by trying to resolve the relation yourself rather than letting hibernate itself do it. (Correct me if I wrong thinking this way)

2. Changing my `User` entity to use `FetchMode.JOIN`.

```java
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private List<Article> articles;
    ...

}
```

This is the same as telling hibernate to eagerly load the below collection no matter what. I don't want this either.

3. Setting `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` to `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true`. Not in the favor of this either since this is just a band aid for `LazyInitializationExceptions`.
4. Any other solutions that just makes your forget about `LazyInitializationException` by keeping the session open throughout the lifecycle of the request.

Comment: You need to open a new session and reattach the detached entity. For example by calling `update`.

Comment: Doing this just instantly resolves all the relations in the entity without me specifying which one I want to resolve, even before calling `Hibernate.initialize(...)`. I don't want this. I want to explicitly specify what I want to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

Please note this answers assumes that Spring Data JPA can be used.

Helpful can be [full dynamic usage of EntityGraphs](https://github.com/Cosium/spring-data-jpa-entity-graph)

> Entity Graphs give us a possibility to define fetch plans and declare which
> relations (attributes) have to be queried from the database.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Cosium/spring-data-jpa-entity-graph/blob/master/doc/MAIN.md)

You can do something similar to this

```
productRepository.findById(1L, EntityGraphUtils.fromAttributePaths(“article, “comments”));
```

And pass all necessary params (relations) based on user selection to the `EntityGraphUtils.fromAttributePaths` method.
This give us possibility to fetch only necessary data.

Additional resources:

1. [Sample project](https://github.com/Cosium/spring-data-jpa-entity-graph-sample)
2. [Spring Blog mentioned this extension](https://spring.io/blog/2021/01/05/this-week-in-spring-january-5th-2020-10th-anniversary-edition)
3. [JPA EntityGraph](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph)
4. [EntityGraph](https://softwarehut.com/blog/tech/no-lazyinitializationexception-use-jpa-2-1-entity-graph)

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround I've used is to skip any child resolver and just load additional entities conditionally in the base resolver.

```
@DgsQuery
public User getUserById(@InputArgument UUID id) {
    var user = userService.findById(id);
    if (dfe.getSelectionSet().contains("articles") {
        Hibernate.initialize(user.getArticles());
    }
    return user;
}
```