# How can I use a non-nullable subfield with netflix dgs / springboot / kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, netflix-dgs

Right now, my project uses netflix/springboot/kotlin.

I want to have an SDL like:

```
type Shows {
  name: String!
  writer: Writer!
}

type Writer {
  name: String!
}
```

In this case, a show *must* have a writer.

When I codegen, I get the relevant Kotlin types.

Now, if I want to implement:

```
...
@DgsData(parent = 'Query', field = 'show')
fun show(@InputArgument id: String): GeneratedShow {
  val show = ShowService.getShow(id);
  // I can't return `show` here because `show` only has `name` and `writerId`.
}
```

My `ShowService.getShow` type only returns a `name` and a `writerId` and I don't want to force my function to have to "hydrate" (extra network call) the `writer` on every graphql call. This would be a waste of resources even if my client does not specify the `writer` subfield.

But I cannot get this to compile because this function requires a `writer` field on it. I also don't want to make `writer` a nullable field in my schema, because it *is* required.

How do you solve this issue?

Comment: I know that one option is to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71613565/3843383, where I can provide an "empty" list if the request did not include the subfield I'm interested in, but that feels like a bit too manual and not typesafe.